# Machine learning / sentiment analysis - is it possible to effectively and safely remove stopwords from text?

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

Based on my knowledge of text learning, we want to stem and remove stop words to reduce the entropy of our data. However, a stop word like "not" could have a huge impact on the meaning and sentiment of a comment. For example:

> I did not like the movie

turns into:

> I did like the movie

If I just leave the stopwords in the text, then I'm assuming their significance would be small enough that it wouldn't matter, it would just take longer to train my classifier.

Are these two tradeoffs I'm perceiving accurate, or is there a best of both worlds in terms of reducing insignificant features without messing up the sentiment of a text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it need to be an all or nothing decision? If the stop word list is only a couple thousand words long, you could just go through the list by hand and keep only the ones that are probably low-information for sentiment analysis.  e.g. prune "the" and "a", but keep "not".

I'd probably error on the side of removing any word from the stop word list that you think *might* provide useful information.  If the word isn't actually useful, the learner will figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

Negative words should first be converted to positive ones, for instance I don't like -> I dislike.
Only after performing such process, you may remove the stop words. To do this, use wordnet.synsets.